# Session will not get time out because of scheduler

Tags: java, spring-mvc, session-timeout

I've developed an application in Spring MVC and Hibernate. In that I've used a security filter for checking session timeout. If the session is null then the filter redirects the current page to login page. And I've also added a **scheduler** that runs every minute for sending **emails**. So my problem is that the session will not be null at any point. Is there a way to make the session null after 10 minutes?

Comment: How is your scheduler linked to a session?

Comment: When I stop the scheduler the session will be null, but in other case the session is not null

Comment: Sorry, but I am missing something here. Sessions are kept "alive" with a timer. Everytime a request comes in for a session, the timer is reset to its timeout value. So the question would be: how come your scheduler is keeping your sessions alive? Also, in your question you seem to talk about a single session, but there could be several. Are they all kept alive?

Comment: Sorry I mistaken ,I was not properly tested the app.You are right session is not linked with scheduler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Session time can be reset when any request comes from browser. But in your case, you are running a scheduler which is no where related to bowser request. Most probably this is not because of your scheduler. If you can share your scheduler code, i can help you some more.

Comment: I've figured it out, I am confused with the names of the session object.Thanks for your answer..